# yii2 - how to add new column with default value via schema

Tags: yii2

how to add new column with default value via schema?
I make as this:

```
$this->addColumn('users', 'email_notification', Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT . ' AFTER auth_key DEFAULT 0  ');
```

but it's not working..

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this, `type` parameter accepts `ColumnSchemaBuilder` as well.

```
$this->addColumn('users', 'email_notification', $this->smallInteger()->defaultValue(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you 'use' the yii\db\Schema

```
use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;
```

Answer (score 1):

I did that and it work for me.

`$this->addColumn('{{%tbl_name}}','field_name',Schema::TYPE_INTEGER."(11) DEFAULT 1");`

Comment: for new version you can do something like:
$this->addColumn('table_name', 'column_name', $this->tinyInteger() . " DEFAULT 0");